# xmlstarlet select query on invalid xhtml

Tags: xml, xmlstarlet

I try to query an xhtml file to extract the titel but fail to do so.

The 'file' is the output file of wget of [this webpage](https://oeil.secure.europarl.europa.eu/oeil/popups/ficheprocedure.do?lang=en&reference=2019/2907(DEA)).

Element with full XPath /html/body/div[1](https://oeil.secure.europarl.europa.eu/oeil/popups/ficheprocedure.do?lang=en&reference=2019/2907(DEA))/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[3]/div[1](https://oeil.secure.europarl.europa.eu/oeil/popups/ficheprocedure.do?lang=en&reference=2019/2907(DEA))/div/div[3]/div/div/div/div/span[1](https://oeil.secure.europarl.europa.eu/oeil/popups/ficheprocedure.do?lang=en&reference=2019/2907(DEA)):

```
<span class="ep_name"> Trans-European energy infrastructure: Union list of projects of common interest </span>
```

Desired output:

```
Trans-European energy infrastructure: Union list of projects of common interest
```

Tried:

```
xmlstarlet sel -N n="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" -t -m "/n:html/n:body/n:div[1]/n:div[2]/n:div[3]/n:div/n:div[3]/n:div[1]/n:div/n:div[3]/n:div/n:div/n:div/n:div/n:span[1][@class='ep_name']" -v . -n file
```

I'm getting an entire list of errors; everything from 'Opening and ending tag mismatch' to 'Premature end of data in tag' of many tags, including body. xmlstarlet val gives me 'invalid' and xmlstarlet el the following:

```
html
html/head
html/head/title
html/head/meta
html/head/meta
html/head/meta/meta
html/head/meta/meta
html/head/meta/meta
html/head/meta/meta
html/head/meta/meta
html/head/meta/meta
html/head/meta/meta
html/head/meta/meta
html/head/meta/meta
html/head/meta/meta
html/head/meta/meta
html/head/meta/meta
html/head/meta/meta/meta
html/head/meta/meta/meta
html/head/meta/meta/meta
html/head/meta/meta/style
html/head/meta/meta/style
html/head/meta/meta/style
html/head/meta/meta/style
html/head/meta/meta/style
html/head/meta/meta/script
html/head/meta/meta/script
html/head/meta/meta/script
html/head/meta/meta/script
html/head/meta/meta/script
html/head/meta/meta/script
html/head/meta/meta/script
html/head/meta/meta/script
html/head/meta/meta/script
html/head/meta/meta/script
html/head/meta/meta/script
html/head/meta/meta/script
html/head/meta/meta/script
html/head/meta/meta/script
html/head/meta/meta/script
html/head/meta/meta/script
html/head/meta/meta/script
html/head/meta/meta/script
html/head/meta/meta/script
html/head/meta/meta/script
html/head/meta/meta/script
html/head/meta/meta/script
procedure:66.70: Specification mandate value for attribute defer
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/oeil/js/cookie-policy.js" defer></script>
```

Is it possible xmlstarlet cannot accesss what I'm trying to query?
What would be a solution?
Using sed would be very tricky since little but the title is unique in the file.

Answer (score 1):

the document at https://oeil.secure.europarl.europa.eu/oeil/popups/ficheprocedure.do?lang=en&reference=2019/2907(DEA) doesn't seem to be well formed XML

instead you could try using

```
 xmllint --html --xpath "//title" <your-file>
```

or in one line:

```
curl -sL "https://oeil.secure.europarl.europa.eu/oeil/popups/ficheprocedure.do?lang=en&reference=2019/2907(DEA)" | xmllint --html --xpath "//title/text()" - 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

It was indeed due to not well-formed xml.

Fix:

```
xmlstarlet fo -o -R -H -D file 2>/dev/null
```

Then the command mentioned above.